# How to remove all characters before specific character in array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I have a comma-separated string being pulled into my application from a web service, which lists a user's roles. What I need to do with this string is turn it into an array, so I can then process it for my end result. I've successfully converted the string to an array with jQuery, which is goal #1. Goal #2, which I don't know how to do, is take the newly created array, and remove all characters before any array item that contains '/', including '/'.

I created a simple work-in-progress JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfo4966/

The string I receive is the following:
`ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC`

`ABCD/` in the string above can change, and may be `XYZ`, `MNO`, etc.

To convert to an array, I've done the following:

```
var importUserRole = 'ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC';
var currentUserRole = importUserRole.split(',');
```

Using `console.log`, I get the following result:

```
["ABCD", "ABCD/Admin", "ABCD/DataManagement", "ABCD/XYZTeam", "ABCD/DriverUsers", "ABCD/RISC"]
```

I'm now at the point where I need the code to look at each index of array, and if `/` exists, remove all characters before `/` including `/`.

I've searched for a solution, but the JS solutions I've found are for removing characters after a particular character, and are not quite what I need to get this done.

Comment: are there more than one slashes inside?

Comment: Good question. Fortunately, there will always be either 1 slash or no slash.  Never more than 1. If no slash, I need to keep it as it is.

Comment: you could split on slash and take the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single `for` loop to go through the array, then `split()` the values by `/` and retrieve the last value of that resulting array using `pop()`. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentUserRole.length; i++) {
    var data = currentUserRole[i].split('/');
    currentUserRole[i] = data.pop();
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6zmbakc6/)

The benefit of using `pop()` over an explicit index, eg `[1]`, is that this code won't break if there are no or multiple slashes within the string.

You could go one step further and make this more succinct by using `map()`:

```js
var importUserRole = 'ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC';
var currentUserRole = importUserRole.split(',').map(function(user) {
  return user.split('/').pop();
});

console.log(currentUserRole);
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. This solution is the most simple, vanilla, and straight forward. It works the best for me.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and perform this string replace:

```
currentUserRole.forEach(function (role) {
  role = role.replace(/(.*\/)/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var A=['ABCD','ABCD/Admin','ABCD/DataManagement','ABCD/XYZTeam','ABCD/DriverUsers','ABCD/RISC'];
    $.each(A,function(i,v){
        if(v.indexOf('/')){
            var e=v.split('/');
            A[i]=e[e.length-1];
        }
    })
    console.log(A);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your post Durga. It works well. There is one solution that is a little easier for me to use in my code. But I upticked your answer because it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the unwanted parts.

```js
var array = ["ABCD", "ABCD/Admin", "ABCD/DataManagement", "ABCD/XYZTeam", "ABCD/DriverUsers", "ABCD/RISC"];
array = array.map(function (a) {
    return a.replace(/^.*\//, '');
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var importUserRole = 'ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC';
var currentUserRole = importUserRole.split(',');

for(i=0;i<currentUserRole.length;i++ ){
  result = currentUserRole[i].split('/');
  if(result[1]){
    console.log(result[1]+'-'+i);
  }  
  else{
     console.log(result[0]+'-'+i);
  }
}
```

In console, you will get required result and array index

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method as you all ready know [string split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) and then use the pop method that will remove the last index of the array and return the value remove [pop method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop)

```
var importUserRole = ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC';
var currentUserRole = importUserRole.split(',');

for(var x = 0; x < currentUserRole.length; x++;){
var data = currentUserRole[x].split('/');
currentUserRole[x] = data.pop();       
}
```

Here is a long way

You can  iterate the array as you have done then check if includes the caracter '/' you will take the indexOf and substact the string after the  '/' 
[substring method in javaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring)

```
var importUserRole = 'ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC';
var currentUserRole = importUserRole.split(',');

 for(var x = 0; x < currentUserRole.length; x++){
  if(currentUserRole[x].includes('/')){
    var lastIndex =  currentUserRole[x].indexOf('/');
    currentUserRole[x] = currentUserRole[x].substr(lastIndex+1);      
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this;

```js
var iur = 'ABCD,ABCD/Admin,ABCD/DataManagement,ABCD/XYZTeam,ABCD/DriverUsers,ABCD/RISC',
    arr = iur.split(",").map(s => s.split("/").pop());
console.log(arr);
```